# Explanation for this complicated 'is not assignable to type' error in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to move my React project to Typescript, but without Typescript experience. I have a Component which is defined as follows (trimmed down):

```
interface InputProps {
  handleKeyDown?: (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  placeholder: string;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
}
const Input: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLInputElement, InputProps> = (
      ^^^^^
  { handleKeyDown, placeholder, style }: InputProps,
  ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>
): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <input
      ref={ref}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      type="text"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      style={style}
    />
  );
};
export const ForwardedInput = React.forwardRef(Input);
```

Now I am getting the following TypeScript error on `const Input`, and it's a bit too complicated for me to untangle:

```
TS2322: Type '({ handleKeyDown, placeholder, style }: InputProps, ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>) => JSX.Element' 
is not assignable to type 'ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>'.
  Types of parameters 'ref' and 'ref' are incompatible.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null> | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | null' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>'.
```

I'm guessing I need to fix this by changing `ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>` into something else, but I don't know how, because I don't know what the error specifically means.

EDIT: The first answer suggested using generic parameters, so I adapted the function as follows:

```
const Input = ({ handleKeyDown, placeholder, style }: InputProps, ref: any) => {
```

I had to type props and ref to prevent typescript warnings (I use `strict: "true"`), and indeed this removes the warnings in the above code example.

But... using any resulted in:

```
ESLint: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)
```

According to [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/when-to-use-never-and-unknown-in-typescript-5e4d6c5799ad/) the use of `any` should be avoided and `unknown` should be used, but although this removes the warning in the function header, it caused a big error in the `ref={ref}` on the input component, stating the same incompatibility with ref as my first error. TypeScript is harder than I thought.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use generic parameters on `React.forwardRef`

```js
export const ForwardedInput = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const { handleKeyDown, placeholder, style } = props;
    return (
      <input
        ref={ref}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        type="text"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        style={style}
      />
    );
  }
);
```

[Playground link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-davinci-1tyfy?file=/src/App.tsx)

If you need to separate `React.forwardRef` call and its function you can use `React.ForwardRefRenderFunction` generic type.

```js
const ForwardInputRefFunction: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLInputElement, InputProps> = (
  props,
  ref
) => {
  const { handleKeyDown, placeholder, style } = props;

  return (
    <input
      ref={ref}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      type="text"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      style={style}
    />
  );
};

const ForwardedInput = React.forwardRef(ForwardInputRefFunction);
```

[Playground link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-brahmagupta-qhjv6?file=/src/App.tsx)

You can explore new types by reading definition files in `node_modules`. To do it in Code sandbox use `Cmd + Left-click` hotkey.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question, though I'm now worried about adding the `any` type. Would that be considered accepted practice? Can it be done better?

Comment: Any is a bad practice. If you often use any in your types you don't need typescript. Do you need to write a type of function that can be passes to `React.forvardRef`?

Comment: You should use types of React library. When you will update to newer version of React  you will have error "Types are incompatible" in such places. It will help you to prevent bugs in your code.